# Positive 4-form

Tags: linear-algebra, quadratic-forms, real-algebraic-geometry, multilinear-algebra

Denote by $W$ the space of all symmetric bilinear forms on $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Let $Q$ be a quadratic form on $W$.
Suppose that $Q(b)\geqslant 0$ for any $b\in W$ such that $b(X,Y)=\ell(X)\cdot\ell(Y)$ for some linear function $\ell$.

> Is it possible to find a nonnegative quadratic form $\tilde Q$ such that $\tilde Q(b)=Q(b)$ for any $b$ as above?

**Comments**

- The forms $b$ as above (up to sign) can be described by quadratic equations
  $$b(X,Y)\cdot b(Z,W)=b(X,Z)\cdot b(Y,W).$$ This leads to a [more general version](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/455148/) of this question, but it has a negative answer (thanks to Terry Tao).
- I know that the answer is yes for $n=2$.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

*(6 October 2023) I'll leave the original argument below because it seems that many people liked it, but, in fact, it wanders around and introduces a lot of unnecessary information, which obscures the essential point, so here is a cleaned up version:*

The answer 'yes' when $n\le 3$ but 'no' when $n\ge4$: Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, so $W = S^2(V^*)$ and the quadratic forms on $W$ are $S^2(W^*) = S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr) = S^2(S^2(V))$ (since $S^2(V^*)$ is canonically isomorphic to $S^2(V)^*$).  The (linear) 'multiplication map' $\mu:S^2(S^2(V))\to S^4(V)$ is surjective. Thus, each quadratic form on $W$ defines a quartic function on $V^*$, and every quartic function on $V^*$ is of the form $\mu(Q)$ for some $Q\in S^2(W^*)$.

The question is whether every non-negative quartic function on $V^*$ is of the form $\mu(Q)$ for some *non-negative* quadratic form $Q \in S^2(W^*)$.  This is equivalent to asking whether every non-negative quartic function on $V^*$ is a sum of squares of quadratic functions on $V^*$.

However, it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem) that for $n\ge4$, there exist non-negative quartic polynomials $P$ on $V^*$ that *cannot* be written as a sum of squares of quadratic polynomials on $V^*$, while, for $n\le 3$, any non-negative quartic polynomial $P$ on $V^*$ *can* be written as a sum of squares of quadratic polynomials.

**Original Argument:**

The answer 'yes' when $n\le 3$ but 'no' when $n\ge4$.  Here is why:

Let $V = \mathbb{R}^n$, so $W = S^2(V^*)$ and the quadratic forms on $W$ are $S^2(W^*) = S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr)$.  It is known that there is a canonical $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-invariant exact sequence
$$
0\longrightarrow \Lambda^4(V)\longrightarrow S^2\bigl(\Lambda^2(V)\bigr)\longrightarrow S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr)\longrightarrow S^4(V)\longrightarrow 0,
$$
thus, there is a $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-module $K(V)$ such that
$$
S^2\bigl(\Lambda^2(V)\bigr) = \Lambda^4(V)\oplus K(V)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr) = S^4(V)\oplus K(V).
$$
The module $K(V)$ is $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-irreducible and of dimension $n^2(n^2{-}1)/12$. It is exactly the set of quadratic forms $Q$ on $W$ that vanish on all of the symmetric bilinear forms on $V$ of the form $B(v,w) = \ell(v)\ell(w)$ for some $\ell\in V^*$.  (The quadratic forms with this latter property must be some $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-invariant submodule of $S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr)$, and it clearly does not contain $S^4(V)$.)

Suppose that $Q$ be nonnegative on all of the rank 1 elements of $W$.  This is equivalent to the condition that, when we write $Q = Q' + Q''$, with $Q'\in S^4(V)$ and $Q''\in K(V)$, then $Q'$, when considered as a quartic polynomial on $V^*$, be a nonnegative quartic polynomial.

If $\tilde Q$ were a non-negative quadratic form on $W$, then it would be a sum of squares of linear functions on $W$, and hence, if $\tilde Q - Q$ lay in $K(V)$, it would follow that $Q'$ would be a sum of squares of quadratic functions on $V^*$.

However, it is [known](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilbert%27s_seventeenth_problem) that for $n\ge4$, there exist non-negative quartic polynomials $Q'$ on $V^*$ that *cannot* be written as a sum of squares of quadratic polynomials on $V^*$.

Thus, for $n\ge 4$, the answer to the OP's question is 'no'.

Meanwhile, when $n\le 3$, every non-negative quartic polynomial in $n$ variables is a sum of squares of quadratic polynomials in those $n$ variables, so the above analysis shows that, when $Q = Q' + Q''$ where $Q'\in S^4(V)$ is a nonnegative function on $V^*$ and $Q''\in K(V)$, there does exist a nonnegative quadratic $\tilde Q\in S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr)$ such that $\tilde Q - Q$ lies in $K(V)$.

Comment: Thank you very much. I guess you wanted to say, but did not say that $K(V)$ is the space of curvature tensors on $V$.

Comment: @AntonPetrunin:  Yes, of course that's true.  It's interesting that $K(V)$ is irreducible as a $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-module, whereas it's reducible as an $\mathrm{SO}(V)$-module (which is the way we usually think of it).

Comment: Also, for another way that this $\mathrm{GL}(V)$ modules shows up, see my answer at  https://mathoverflow.net/q/100372.

Comment: Extremely nice!  Can you give a pointer for more background on that exact sequence, and its connection with the space of curvature tensors?

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine:  There's not that much to say.  The usual multiplicity formulae in $\mathrm{GL}(V)$-representation theory show that $S^2(\Lambda^2(V))\simeq \Lambda^4(V)\oplus K(V)$ while $S^2(S^2(V))\simeq S^4(V)\oplus K(V)$, where $K(V)$ is irreducible.  The center map of the exact sequence on decomposable elements is $$(v_1\wedge v_2)\circ(v_3\wedge v_4)\longmapsto (v_1\circ v_3)\circ(v_2\circ v_4)- (v_1\circ v_4)\circ(v_2\circ v_3).$$ It's clearly nonzero, so it has to match the two copies of $K(V)$, making $\Lambda^4(V)$ be the kernel and $S^4(V)$ be the cokernel.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine:  Oh, and I should have pointed out that, since $S^2(V^*)$ is canonically isomorphic to $\bigl(S^2(V)\bigr)^*$, we also have $S^2\bigl(S^2(V^*)^*\bigr)$ is canonically isomorphic to $S^2(S^2(V))$.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine:  I forgot to say what this has to do with curvature: As one knows, the Riemann curvature tensor of a metric $g$ is a section of $S^2(\Lambda^2(T^*M))$. Since it is second order in $g$, which is a section of $S^2(T^*M)$, the curvature must be computable from the second derivatives of $g$, i.e., from something like $S^2(T^*M)\otimes S^2(T^*M)$. By the time one cuts away the coordinate (or connection) dependence of this section, one  is left with some quotient of $S^2(S^2(T^*M))$, and the only part that can match with the Riemann curvature tensor is the $K(T^*M)$ component.